# How to detect if content have more then one line in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have template like this:

```
<span class="collapsibleBox">
     <a ng-show="visible" ng-click="hide()" class="minus">
         <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i>
     </a>
     <a ng-show="!visible" ng-click="show()" class="plus">
         <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
     </a>
    <div ng-show="visible || preview" ng-class="preview ? 'previewBox' : 'contentBlock'"  ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></div>
</span>
```

with css:

```
.api .previewBox {
  height: 1.25em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And I need to not show plus and minus sign icons when div with class htmlContent is only one line, how can I do this in Angular.

Comment: This isn't an angular question.

Comment: @mattytommo It's angular app and I need to do this in angular.

Comment: What do you mean by "content"? Is it element(s) inside the anchor tag or inside the .collapsiblebox?

Comment: @user2989484 the div with class htmlContent.

Comment: What do you mean by "only one line"? I don't know what your object looks like, but can't you do something like htmlContent.children or htmlContent.length to check if it's more than one element?

Comment: Are you saying you want to show the first line of content, and if there's more content to be seen, allow them to click a button to show the rest of the lines?

Comment: @jcubic Would a reasonable solution be to check the string length of the line? This seems a bit cleaner than trying to figure out if a given piece of text has a line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this directive:

```
module.directive('oneLine', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            text: '=',
            oneLine: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            angular.element(window).bind('resize', function() {
                var height = $element.html('M').show().height();
                $element.html($scope.text);
                $scope.oneLine = height == $element.height();
                $element.hide();
                if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(); // $scope throw "digest in progress" exception
                }
            }).trigger('resize');
        }
    };
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<span class="collapsibleBox">
    <span ng-hide="hideButtons">
         <a ng-show="visible" ng-click="hide()" class="minus">
             <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i>
         </a>
         <a ng-show="!visible" ng-click="show()" class="plus">
             <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
         </a>
    </span>
    <div class="contentBlock" one-line="hideButtons" text="htmlContent"></div>
    <div ng-show="visible || preview" ng-class="preview ? 'previewBox' : 'contentBlock'"  ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set your CSS to only show one line, but show ellipses when the text overflows.  You don't get +/- buttons, but it might be usable for you.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: Unfortunately I need those buttons.